# C++ move data in class constructor without copy

Tags: c++, constructor, move

I'm learning about move semantics and I'm wondering which is the correct way to move data to a class constructor without copying them. For example, assume to have a `Container` class, which has only a `std::vector<int>` as member data. I want to **first** initialize and build that vector somewhere, **then** I want to create a `Container` object and move the content of the vector to its member data with no copy. As far as I understood (and tested), the following code works:

```
class Container
{
    std::vector<int> m_data;
public:
    Container(std::vector<int>&& data) : m_data{std::move(data)} {};
};

// Somewhere else
std::vector<int> data = someFunction();
// Do more stuff in between
Container container(std::move(data));
```

If I try to access elements with `data[1]` after that, it results in a segfault, which is correct, because `data` has been moved `container.m_data`.

**Question**: is this the correct way to solve the problem I'm facing? Is there maybe a more elegant and clean way (e.g. to avoid the double usage of `std::move()` in both the constructor and the call to the constructor)?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: no, this is correct

Comment: To top @bloody 's comment off... once you start declaring one of "the five", you should follow the rule of five. Here you should use the rule of zero.

Comment: @bloody a compiler generated move constructor for `Container` doesnt have a `std::vector` argument

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Right, thanks for the point. Op's pattern slightly misled me (and not only me apparently:)